# Migrations not running because of PRIMARY KEY set to NULL?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I was doing migrations for my DB in Laravel, but this error keeps appearing. I thought that I fixed it but not. The error says:

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1171 All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead**

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1171 All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead (SQL: creat

e table `articulos` (`id` bigint unsigned not null, `descuento_id` bigint unsigned not null, `unidad_medida` varchar(40) not null, `categoria` varchar(50) nul

l, `nombre` varchar(100) not null, `codigo_comercial` varchar(50) null, `codigo_interno` varchar(35) null, `tipo` enum('interno', 'externo') not null default

'externo', `marca` varchar(50) null, `existencia` double(8, 2) not null default '0', `status` enum('activo', 'suspendido') not null default 'activo', `stock`

tinyint null auto_increment primary key, `descripcion` text null, `max` int null, `min` int null, `codigo_producto_sat` varchar(255) null, `codigo_unidad_sat`

varchar(255) null, `subcategoria` varchar(50) null, `subsubcategoria` varchar(50) null, `modelo` varchar(255) null, `presentaciones` json null, `imagen` varc

har(255) null, `impuestos_compra` json not null, `impuestos_venta` json not null, `validar_peso` enum('si', 'no') not null default 'no', `deleted_at` timestam

p null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')**

My migration file:

```
Schema::create('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('descuento_id');
        $table->string('categoria' , 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('nombre' , 100);
        $table->string('codigo_comercial' , 50)->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('codigo_interno' , 35)->nullable();
        $table->enum('tipo' , ['interno' , 'externo'])->default('externo');
        $table->string('marca' , 50)->nullable();
        $table->double('existencia' , 8 , 2)->default('0');
        $table->enum('status' , ['activo' , 'suspendido'])->default('activo');
        $table->tinyInteger('stock' , 1)->nullable();
        $table->text('descripcion')->nullable();
        $table->integer('max')->nullable();
        $table->integer('min')->nullable();
        $table->string('unidad_medida' , 40);
        $table->string('codigo_producto_sat' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('codigo_unidad_sat' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('subcategoria' , 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('subsubcategoria', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('modelo' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->json('presentaciones')->nullable();
        $table->string('imagen' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->json('impuestos_compra');
        $table->json('impuestos_venta');
        $table->enum('validar_peso' , ['si' , 'no'])->default('no');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't see anything in this migration that would explicitly set a primary key. I'd recommend using `$table->bigIncrements('id');` instead of `$table->unsignedBigInteger('id');` to do so, that may fix your issue but I'm not 100% sure. Is there any more info in the error that shows the sql being generated by the migration? That would help a lot!

Comment: Hello! I just added the query message the error shows.

Comment: or simply ``$table->id();``. ``$table->bigIncrements('id');`` is an alias of ``$table->id()``

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it. TinyInt shouldn't be nullable:

```
$table->tinyInteger('stock' , 1)->nullable();
```

Instead, I should type like this:

```
$table->tinyInteger('stock' , 1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: so `stock` is your auto incrementing field, not `id` ? the second argument to the integer fields is a `bool` and it is for `autoincrement` ... not sure why you wouldn't make the `id` field auto increment since that is the identifier (hence 'id')